# react-native-dropdown-picker, how to get selected index from Items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dropdown

I have used react-native-dropdown-picker to listed array of items. I don't know how to get selected index. I have tried below code but am getting "Undefined" value.

Example code:

```
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';

function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {label: 'Apple', value: 'apple'},
    {label: 'Banana', value: 'banana'}
  ]);

  return (
    <DropDownPicker
      open={open}
      value={value}
      items={items}
      setOpen={setOpen}
      setValue={setValue}
      setItems={setItems}
      onChangeValue={(value, index) => {
        console.log("selected value",value);
        console.log("selected Index",index);
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Expected: I need selected index which is selected from items.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation `onChangeValue` only returns the value, so you would neet to get the index from your array, like

```
getIndex = (value) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].value == value) {
      return index;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Better option would be items.findIndex(item=>item.value===value)

Comment: Thanks for the help. The code working fine. for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    let b = items.findIndex(item=>item.value===value);
                    console.log("Your ITEM index", b);
                  }